# How to set selected item in bean in <p:dataList>

Tags: jsf, mobile, primefaces, facelets

I am using `p:dataList` because I am developing a PrimeFaces mobile view displaying a list of items. When clicking on any item, another `pm:view` of the same view should be displayed. But the bean should be notified of the selected item.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to update the bean successfully: `<p:ajax>` inside dataTable throws this exception:

```
<p:ajax> Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

Using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside the iterative element  fails too because I get:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource
```

This is my code:

```
<pm:view  id="instrumentsView" >
    <pm:content >
        <h:form id="instrumentsList" >                            
            <p:dataList var="instrument" value="#{instrumentBean.subscribedInstruments}" >
                <h:outputLink value="#newView" >#{instrument.longName}</h:outputLink>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instrument}" target="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument}" />
            </p:dataList>
        </h:form>
    </pm:content>
</pm:view>
```

Clearly, I am using dataList and outputLink because as far as I understand, they are the components optimized for the use in PrimeFaces mobile lists. But I am available to find other options if necessary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PM, but can't you just use an [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) component? E.g. `<h/p:commandLink>` or `<h/p:commandButton>`. Or otherwise, if you want GET instead of POST, pass its ID as `<f:param>` and use `<f:viewParam>` on target view to convert, validate and set it?

Comment: @BalusC, I have tried with h:commandLink: both the JS invoked `onclick` and `href` element differ, for handling internal navigation to another `pm:view` in the same `f:view`. If I don't find anothe solution I'll try developing my first custom component!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf) (example titled **News**) the correct way of handling the problem:

```
<p:dataList var="instrument" value="#{instrumentBean.subscribedInstruments}" >
    <p:column >
        <p:commandLink value="#{instrument.longName}" action="pm:newView" update=":compId">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instrument}" target="#{instrumentBean.selectedInstrument}" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataList>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a topic explaining this in the primefaces documentation.

Selecting Data (page 124) 
indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf
http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

Here is the content

```
    <h:form id="carForm">
    <p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}" columns="3" rows="12">
        <p:panel header="#{car.model}">
            <p:commandLink update=":carForm:display" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}"
                    target="#{carBean.selectedCar}"
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataGrid>
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/#{car.manufacturer}.jpg" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Model:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{carBean.selectedCar.year}" />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```